# Does Amazon DMS support replicating one table from a schema to a different schema of the same table?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, aws-dms

I'm trying to setup replication between two MySQL RDS instances for one table only. I would like to replicate for example, schema1.users to schema2.users.

Under Mapping rules, I'm able to specify the schema and table names but I think they are for source only but I can't seem to find anything about specifying target schema and table name.

Thus I would like to know if it's a limitation of this service or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

In you case, you can try the rule below

```json
{
    "rules": [
      {
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "1",
        "object-locator": {
          "schema-name": "schema1",
          "table-name": "users"
        },
        "rule-action": "include"
      },
      {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "2",
        "rule-name": "2",
        "rule-target": "schema",
        "object-locator": {
          "schema-name": "schema1"
        },
        "rule-action": "rename",
        "value": "schema2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

It should replicate the users table from the schema1 to the schema2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html